# How to change password for Django Social auth loggedin Twitter user

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth

I am using social-auth along with userena and friends app. i want to provide a functionality for twitter loggedin users to change their password using django change password form but for twitter user current password is not available to change it so please anyone can help me with it
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why it's not available to change? A user created by django-social-auth will have an unusable password by default, you can check that by doing  `user.has_usable_password()` and force the new one if not set, otherwise you can validate the current user password before changing it.

Comment: Thanks omab, By using the user.has_usable_password() i have written my custom view to check old password and save new password. once again thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can check a users password was set or not by using `user.has_usable_password()` as [omab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/385822/omab) said in the above comment.